# Mint 15 freezes at startup

Tags: linux-mint, boot, freeze

Yesterday I installed Mint 15 MATE on my laptop. Everything worked perfectly, so I installed some packages (python-django, mysql-server, and some other python modules). I also ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. Finally I selected a NVIDIA proprietary driver recommended by Mint, and changed the desktop icons.

I did nothing else, and everything worked until today. I powered on the laptop, and the first thing I saw was an "old-fashioned" way of asking for the encryption password at startup, that looks almost like a console, when yesterday was a little Mint logo and a window for the input. After that the login screen appears, and then it freezes.

Sometimes it happens at the login screen (even when I'm typing the password, so it gets stuck when I have written only a few characters), and sometimes I'm fast enough to login and see the desktop, but then it freezes anyway. I guess it's just a matter of time before some module gets loaded.

I can move the mouse, but nothing else works.

What can I do to fix this? I am willing to give you more information if you explain me how. I tried to pause booting sequence to see if there is something wrong (I have been able to see 2 FAILS, one relative to the avahi daemon, but I don't know how to pause the sequence in order to read it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had also some trouble with my Nvidia Card at boot up and occasionnal freeze.
What i've done was to add 'nomodeset' to the grub boot option.
You should try it... if it solve the problem you can make the change permanent :

Edit /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add the 'nomodeset' option :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Update Grub :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: But, how can I do this? I can't login and open a terminal before it gets stuck

Comment: You can try changing it in the grub menu first... hold shift at boot time to show it (if it don't appear by default).

Comment: Not appearing by default, nor holding shift at boot time. Can I do it through the live cd?

Comment: Yes it's possible via chroot for applying update-grub. But it's a bit complicated. Are you sure holding the shift key doesn't do anything ?

Comment: Maybe you can switch to a console (CTRL+ALT+F2) before logging to the xsession.